# I'm trying to find a group of objects with similar names in SQL ORACLE but i'm getting an error that i can't solve

Tags: sql, oracle

**I don't know what's wrong.**

**Both this queries return the following error**:

SQL Error [936] [42000]: ORA-00936: missing expression

**Queries:**

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE owner = 'hatemalifeDatabase' AND OBJECT_TYPE = 'SEQUENCE' AND OBJECT_NAME = 'Object name changed for security reasons'

SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE owner = 'WATDATABASE' AND OBJECT_TYPE = 'SEQUENCE' AND OBJECT_NAME LIKE = '%SECURITYREASONS%'
```

---

**This querie is working normally and i modified her to find the alike objects.**

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE owner = 'IhateAliens' AND OBJECT_TYPE = 'SEQUENCEm' AND OBJECT_NAME = 'qwkrhqwkrqwkrqwr'
```

Comment: The first one from the top list is fine. The second one from the top list has `LIKE =`. It should be simply `LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

do not use '=' with a 'like' condition

[Like condition](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm)